# is varchar(n) saving memory space in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, varchar

If I define a `varchar(25)` and my string is less than 25 characters (e.g. 12 chars), SQL shows the vector of char as a length of 12 and no trailing spaces are added (unlike character does).

My question is the following : behind the fact that SQL displays just the string as it was inserted in the field (or truncated if longer than the maximum length), how Postgresql is storing such a data type?

Is it padding with extra bytes as :

> twelvecharxx............. (length : 25)

or just storing 12 bytes?

I assume this could be more complex internally. I just need to know if the `maximum-length` optional argument is a safety to disallow large string storage or just a performance question (regarding if all the subsequence stored strings are expected to be less or equal to 25 characters).

Comment: downvoter : explain yourself

Comment: Wasn't me, but that could well be a combination of "it's a FAQ" and "It's in the manual".

Answer (score 5):

> SQL defines two primary character types: character varying(n) and
>   character(n), where n is a positive integer. Both of these types can
>   store strings up to n characters in length. An attempt to store a
>   longer string into a column of these types will result in an error,
>   unless the excess characters are all spaces, in which case the string
>   will be truncated to the maximum length. (This somewhat bizarre
>   exception is required by the SQL standard.) If the string to be stored
>   is shorter than the declared length, values of type character will be
>   space-padded; values of type character varying will simply store the
>   shorter string.

and

> The storage requirement for a short string (up to 126 bytes) is 1 byte
>   plus the actual string, which includes the space padding in the case
>   of character. Longer strings have 4 bytes overhead instead of 1.

finally

> Tip: There are no performance differences between these three types,
>   apart from increased storage size when using the blank-padded type,
>   and a few extra cycles to check the length when storing into a
>   length-constrained column. While character(n) has performance
>   advantages in some other database systems, it has no such advantages
>   in PostgreSQL.

from [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/datatype-character.html)

Answer (score 0):

No padding is stored for `varchar`, according to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-character.html). For `character` it is, however. There's also some overhead in storing the length of the string.